# How do I get to the HTML of a rendered SSRS 2008 report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to do some manipulation to the HTML code of a rendered SSRS 2008 report (to insert some tags that SSRS 2008 doesn't support). I want to to this through adding JavaScript code in the ReportManager.js file in the SSRS server.

However, a simple "view source" of a render report will show you that my "hooks", or any text that I include in a text box or placeholder are nowhere to be found in the rendered HTML.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you rendering the report? Through the ReportViewer control or something else?

Comment: Deploying it from BIDS, it gives me a URL, and that's what I give my users. I really don't know what you refer to as ReportViewer (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're using the Report Manager as opposed to running your reports in a custom web app. Based on this setup, I'm not sure if you have any options for manipulating the rendered HTML. If you were rendering the report through a custom web app, you would have more control.

Comment: How do you render the reports through a custom web app? Doing something like `string html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http:myreporturl")`?

Comment: No, you need to use the ReportViewer control in an ASP.NET application, or you can use the SSRS Web Services, which give you complete control over the rendering of the report.

Comment: I'd really appreciate some more details, if you can.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345248(v=sql.105).aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: I have some learning to do... Thanks. Add an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can manipulate the report rendering using the standard out-of-the-box Report Manager interface. Your best bet is to create a custom web app using either the [ASP.NET ReportViewer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345248%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or the [Report Server Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and then you can do some manipulation of the report output.

Good luck!